# MySQL SELECT * with same ID from a table based on row click (js) of a previous table with that ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have three tables: **learners**, **sessions** and **enrollments**. Please see relationships image bellow:

[Relationships Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI6vU.png)

Now to explain how I've set this up: I'm using DataTables for sessions, on record click of a session I get a popup with all its record details - I have used something like the below. Plus a further note on this, I'm not using Ajax, only **html**, **php**, **mysql** and **js** to interact with the database:

**Script:**

```
$('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {    
    var data = dataTable.row( this ).data();
    modal.style.display = "block";
    $('#Course').html(data[1]);
    $('#Begin').html(data[2]);
    $('#End').html(data[3]);
    $('#Location').html(data[4]);
    $('#Trainer').html(data[5]);
    $('#Type').html(data[6]);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!--Fetch session prints here-->
<p id="Course"><span id="Course"></p>
<p id="sess_desc">
     <b>Offered: </b><span id="Begin"></span> to <span id="End"></span><br />
     <b>Location: </b><span id="Location"></span><br />
     <b>Trainer: </b><span id="Trainer"></span><br />
     <b>Training Type: </b><span id="Type"></span>
</p>
```

See here: [Popup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYlGH.png)

I'd like to know how to display enrolled learners from the clicked session table. I'm unable to create an SQL query based on the js "click" event of this row, which would allow me to display all enrolments based on clicked rows ID.

I've tried this but it doesn't work for me as I'm unable to structure my query based on the clicked session record:

```
                            <div id="modal_showlearners">
                            <p>Learners enrolled in this session:</p>
                            <form action="#" method="post">
                                <?php
                                    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM enrolments WHERE SessionID = sessions." . $row['ID'] . "") or die (mysqli_error());
                                    while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                        echo $row['SessionID'] . " " . $row['LearnerID'] . " " . $row['FirstName'] . "<br />";
                                    }

                                ?>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Hope I've given enough information, I've been struggling with this for over 2 weeks now. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: if you want to do something to your database based on client side interaction, you need to either submit a form or send an ajax request. one way or another, the server needs to know what happened and update/insert rows accordingly

Comment: also, this is way too much information - we don't really need to know I was able to do this and I was able to do that – this is mostly just seen as noise and decreases the likelihood of someone reading your question all the way through.  Try to edit this question to be a bit more concise about where you hit a wall and what you want to do.  You will get more responses this way.

Comment: I've edited my post. Upon doing this I figured that JS is processed only after PHP, so running lots of PHP scripts on a single page are all processed at once, even the one within the modal popup which I was assuming will be run after the popup pops.

Comment: as I said, to interact with your database based on clicks, you need ajax.  the basic idea is, (1) set up an event that triggers an ajax request on a click event, (2) receive the request on your server, run a query and return either html to display or a json to parse, (3) render the data on your page in the success() callback